# Link Incidence Matrix between two distinct nodes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

My dataframe consists in a binary weight between a pair of electrodes:

```
> head(data)
  Elec1 Elec2 weight
1    C3    C3      0
2    C3    C4      1
3    C3   CP1      1
4    C3   CP2      0
5    C3   CP5      0
6    C3   CP6      1
```

Essentially I have 25 electrodes and its permutations (625 observations) to the other 25 electrodes, including the same electrode, and a binary weight. Let's suppose 1 means connected and 0 means disconnected.

I am trying to build a link matrix in order to analyse this data through different network visualisations.

The end product could be something like this

```
  Elec C3 C4 CP1 CP2 CP5
1   C3  0   1   2   0   0
2   C4  1   1   0   1   0
3   CP1 1   1   1   1   1
4   CP2 0   0   0   2   1
5   CP5 0   1   1   1   1
```

Note there should be a bi-directional logic to it, hence the possible 2s.

I tried `model.matrix` but I could not make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds it useful, I ended up using `library(reshape2)` and specifically `melt` function.

This did the trick, and then I didn't need the bi-directional repetition.

```
table(melt(d, id.var=c("Elec1","Elec2")))
```